# Salesforce Apex Test Class for an auto convert apex class. REceiving errors moving to production

Tags: salesforce, apex, test-class

I have an apex class that works how I want it in the sandbox. Trying to move it to production and need to write a test class. Used an example provided but I continue to get errors when running test that the lead was already converted. Need Help!

```
@isTest 
public class TestAutoConvertLeads{
    static testMethod void createnewlead() {
      User userToCreate = [Select id from user where profile.name='System Administrator' Limit 1];

      Test.startTest();    
      Lead leadToCreate =new Lead();
      List<id> Ids= New List<Id>();
      leadToCreate.ownerid= userToCreate.id;
      leadToCreate.LastName ='Gupta';
      leadToCreate.LeadSource='Partner Referral';
      leadToCreate.Rating='';
      leadToCreate.Status='';
      insert leadToCreate; 

      Ids.add(leadToCreate.id);
      AutoConvertLeads.LeadAssign(Ids);

      Test.stopTest();
   }
}
```

Also adding original apex class:

Comment: Public class AutoConvertLeads
{
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void LeadAssign(List<Id> LeadIds)
    {
            Database.LeadConvert Leadconvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
            Leadconvert.setLeadId(LeadIds[0]);
            LeadStatus Leads= [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
            Leadconvert.setConvertedStatus(Leads.MasterLabel);
           
            Database.LeadConvertResult Leadconverts = Database.convertLead(Leadconvert);
            System.assert(Leadconverts.isSuccess());
   }
}